# Installing Apache Kudu on my mac (Mac Os Sierra 10.12.1) fails to compile during "thirdparty/build-if-necessary.sh"

Tags: macos, apache-kudu

When I'm trying to install Apache Kudu I obtain this error. I couldn't find any information to solve this problem and the only one I could find says that after installing Xcode the problem was solved, but I have already Xcode installed.

```
/kudu/thirdparty/src/llvm-3.9.0.src/projects/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/eprintf.c:14:10: fatal error: 'stdio.h' file not found
#include <stdio.h>
  ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.eprintf.dir/eprintf.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [projects/compiler-rt/lib/builtins/CMakeFiles/clang_rt.eprintf.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 10%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/PseudoLoweringEmitter.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/PDBSymbolUsingNamespace.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/PDBSymDumper.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/RegisterInfoEmitter.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/DbiStream.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/DbiStreamBuilder.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/EnumTables.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/Hash.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/SearchableTableEmitter.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/IndexedStreamData.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/InfoStream.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/InfoStreamBuilder.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/MappedBlockStream.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/ModInfo.cpp.o
[ 10%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/SubtargetEmitter.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/ModStream.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/MsfBuilder.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/TableGen.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/MsfCommon.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/NameHashTable.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/NameMap.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86DisassemblerTables.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/NameMapBuilder.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86ModRMFilters.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/PDBFile.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/X86RecognizableInstr.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/PDBFileBuilder.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object utils/TableGen/CMakeFiles/obj.llvm-tblgen.dir/CTagsEmitter.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/PublicsStream.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/RawError.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/RawSession.cpp.o
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/SymbolStream.cpp.o
[ 11%] Built target obj.llvm-tblgen
[ 11%] Building CXX object lib/DebugInfo/PDB/CMakeFiles/LLVMDebugInfoPDB.dir/Raw/TpiStream.cpp.o
[ 11%] Linking CXX static library ../../libLLVMDebugInfoPDB.a
[ 11%] Built target LLVMDebugInfoPDB
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It would be so nice if someone could help me, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Turns out that for some reason Command Line Tools are not enough. One needs to have the full XCode installed, after which you need to issue:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

After doing that, rerunning `thirdparty/build-if-necessary.sh` built the dependencies for me without any issues.